# Attribute error: object has no attribute on function call

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm getting:

> attribute error: ' Node' object has no attribute 'data'

when trying to use this class method:

```
def deletetotallist(self):
    curr = self.head
    while curr:
        prev = curr.next
        del curr.data
        curr = prev
```

Comment: check your node class and see if it there or not

Comment: The error message is quite clear. Your `Node` object has no `data` attribute. That should immediately ring a bell. Maybe your `Node` class has instead a `value` attribute (another common name for it), or still something else. Voting to close as not reproducible (with the code you have given).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the line:

```
del curr.data
```

The effect of running it is that the *data* field is removed from a *Node* instance.

If your goal is to leave the nodes and links intact while eliminating the data reference, consider setting the data field to *None*:

```
curr.data = None
```